# how to determine the number of k for the k nearest neighbors

Tags: knn

I have about half a million data, and I used 'brute' to find the suitable k, but now the accuracy is still lower, can you tell me how can I do to find the k to improve my accuracy

ans I choose k=sqrt(n) to determine k, but the accuracy is only 46%